# Php Symbol display

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to display a certain currency symbol using php and mysql, table name is fund, the table rows name is symbol. The symbol has to dynamically change depending on the id of that certain row. How would I code that where the user of the app cannot change it? Basically the symbol appears and cannot be edited.

Let me know if I needed to show more code.

```
<label>Price</label>
  Symbol must display here- example: ($)      
<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php value('price'); ?>" />
```

My errors section:

```
<?php
$errors = array();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {    //Check for postback
    if($_POST['price'] == '')
       $errors['price'] = 'Please enter a price.';
    if($_POST['date'] == '')
       $errors['date'] = 'Please enter a date.';
    if(count($errors) == 0){
    //edit funds
    $sql = "UPDATE funds SET price='" . $_POST['price'] . 
    "', date='" . $_POST['date'] . "' WHERE id = " . $_GET['id'];
    query($sql);
    set_flashdata('success', 'Fund updated');
    redirect('index.php');
  }  
 } else {
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM funds WHERE id = ' . $id;
      $results = query($sql);
      $_POST['price'] = $results[0]['price'];
      $_POST['date'] = $results[0]['date'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: You need to use the HTML entity to specify the symbol. Javascript will do the rest. Also it's bad practice to use functions which echo, change value() to `return` a value and use echo when you call it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function chk_symbol($id)
{
    global $sym;
    $array_symbol=array("$","@","%","#");
    $c=count($array_symbol);
    $i=0;
    for($i;$i<$c;$i++)
    {
        if($id==$i)
        {
            $sym=$array_symbol[$i];

        }
    }   

}

//call function which set a value of variable $sym and echo it wherever you want
chk_symbol(0);
echo $sym;

?>
```